# Why am I getting a 413 error upon file upload even though there are adequate file sizes present on the server?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, debugging

for some reason when uploading file and submitting my form, it isn't allowing video uploads that are size of `*MB` (it keeps throwing a `413` error).  Only `*KB` files are successfully going through.

I checked the `php.ini` file on the server and the `upload_max_filesize = 20M`.  I've also checked in Nginx (`client_max_body_size 5000M;`) but I'm not sure why this could possibly be happening.

I was wondering if anyone has any clues as to why I'm experiencing this?

Comment: Is there some kind of error message, or just nothing happens?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff nothing happens.  The error is `413 Request Entity Too Large`.  I'm so stumped on this!

Comment: You can also check `post_max_size`

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's in the `php.ini` file.  I've just checked that and it's `post_max_size = 20M`.

Comment: And the files you're trying to upload are definitely <20M? (Sorry for the dumb question, just making sure.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic it's cool, I understand!  Yeah, they're definitely <20M.

Comment: Maybe also check your webserver? Or are you using artisan serve?

Comment: @onlineThomas hmm, good point.  I'm using Homestead (Vagrant)

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/limit-file-upload-size-in-nginx/amp/

Comment: You could try prompting `phpinfo()` to check whether the modifications you're doing to the `php.ini` file are being applied or not

Comment: @whenitrainsitpours Was changing the nginx config the correct solution?